# Map Web Api MapHttpRoute to Base Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi I have a Controller as shown below,

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class ApiInformationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var info = new ApplicationInformation
        {
            ApplicationName = "Test App",
            DatabaseName = "SQL Server 2012",
            ApplicationVersion = "3.10.0"
        };
        return Json(info, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I also configured the routes in WebApiConfig as I do not want to use RouteConfig separately,

```
private static void ConfigureRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;

        // Web API routes
        _config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "ApiInformation", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional});
        _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
    }
```

When I try and access the base url, I want the ApiInformation to be displayed.
For Example when I try **http://localhost:23175/** I would like the Api to call the Index of ApiInformationController. What am I doing wrong here?

Current when I call the url I am getting the following response,
[image]

Comment: does it work without MapHttpAttributeRoutes ?

Comment: are you use MVC project with API or API project?

Comment: @Vinay - Ashiquizzman has a point. MVC and Web Api are separate frameworks, which each have their own routing, and you need to ensure they have urls that do not conflict. Based on your MVC tags in the question, it looks like you are trying to put your MVC routing in the Web Api config (or, you are just doubling up on your routes, which isn't a good thing). MVC routes should be added to your RouteConfig.cs file, not here.

Comment: Thank you for the help, could you please help me to implement Web APi routing with ApiController. Such that i get the desiredresult when base url is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to modify MapHttpRoute's routeTemplate.

WebApiConfig like,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "ApiInformation", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

And how you receive,

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Index()
{
    var info = new ApplicationInformation
    {
        ApplicationName = "Test App",
        DatabaseName = "SQL Server 2012",
        ApplicationVersion = "3.10.0"
    };
    return Json(info);
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Here http://localhost:23175/api is used to query for data which is working fine. But if some user just try to acces the base url like this http://localhost:23175 iwould like to display ApiInformation.Can i achieve this using ApiController instead of MVC Controller.